# Provider ImagePicker

Tags: flutter, provider, imagepicker

I have a problem with the provider while picking the image from the gallery it doesn't appear in the UI.

I tried to use Text instead and it did work perfectly. I think the problem is with the futureBuilder or something

```
class ImageController extends ChangeNotifier {
   Future<File> _image;

   pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource source) {
       _image = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
       NotificationListener();
   }

  Widget imageFromGallery() {

    return  FutureBuilder<File>(
     future: _image,
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
           null != snapshot.data) {
         Utility.saveImageToPreferences(
             Utility.base64String(snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync()));
         return
          Image.file(
           snapshot.data,

         );
       } else if (null != snapshot.error) {
         return const Text(
           'Error Picking Image',
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
         );
       } else {
         return const Text(
           'No Image Selected',
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
         );
       }
      },
     );
  }
}
```

and this is how i display it from the another widgit

```
Consumer<ImageController>(
                    builder: (context, image,child){
                    return  Provider.of<ImageController>(context).imageFromGallery();
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The consumer already retrieves the `ImageController`. `Consumer` is a nicer way of writing `Provider.of` with a builder to return a widget.

```dart
Consumer<ImageController>(
  builder: (context, imageController, child){
    return  imageController.imageFromGallery();
  },
),
```

Comment: same thing it doesn't appear until i navigate to another page and navigat back

Comment: @MaenAlnassan I don't know what you mean by navigate, maybe show us the entire class and build tree. Also try and add a log to your builder to check if your connection state is changing or not.